# How do I erase old user and become the new user on a iBook G4 I just got from a friend?

Tags: macos, install, ibook

My friend gave me his iBook G4.

I could not login because I did not know his password.

I have the 2 DVD Mac OS Install disks of the laptop.

After I installed these OS X Install discs, once again I was asked for the old user's password.

How do I do a complete wipe out and then reinstall the OS so I can become the new user?

Comment: I think during the installation, there's a point where you have a menu available in which Disk Utility is accessible. You'd use that to delete the partition and recreate a new one. Alternatively, ask your friend for the password.

Comment: I will try keeping an eye for that Disk Utility access. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Dont hit 'continue' after putting in the Install OS disk, instead go to top-left screen where there is a menu with an option to change login password.

Comment: Since you answered your own question (with a correct answer) you should mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't happen to have an OS install disk lying around and don't know the other user's password, consider booting into single-user mode (hold down Command-S while booting (see [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492))), running

```
mount -rw /
rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
reboot
```

It will reboot and go through the setup again. After it finishes, you'll be at a fresh adminstrative user account, and you can just trash their home folder.

Answer (score 0):

When installing the operating system make sure you do an erase and install via the 'options' button during the install. Otherwise all the data will still be there.

As you have a G4 I can assume the install discs are either Tiger (10.4) or Leopard (10.5)

You can find the installation options here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1545

I think this is the cleanest way about completely resetting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and upon researching the possibilities I found one, and only one, that worked. Its actually very simple. Here goes -
1. Boot up computer, holding down apple + s key after you hear the chime, then let go after you see apple image.
2. When you get a flashing text prompt, enter the following 3 lines, making sure to press the  key after each entry - 
 mount -uw /
 rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
 shutdown -h now
3.The computer will automatically shutdown, so you will have to press the power button again. But this time it will boot up like it did the first time it was purchased. You can now begin from scratch, entering your own information/ Be advised, however, setup will take some time.